# Multivariable chain rule problem

Tags: multivariable-calculus

Be $z=f(x,y)$. Consider $g(u,v)=uf(u^2, 2uv)$. Calculate $\dfrac{\partial^2g}{\partial u \, \partial v}(1,1)$ if $f(1,2)=4$, $\nabla f(1,2)=(3,-1)$,  $\dfrac{\partial^2f}{\partial x^2}(1,2)= \dfrac{\partial^2f}{\partial y^2}(1,2)=1$ and $\dfrac{\partial^2f}{\partial x \,\partial y}(1,2)=-1$.

I'm having trouble to solve this. Could someone give me a hint, please? Thanks in advance.

[EDIT] My attempt using the Product Rule and Chain Rule.:

$\dfrac{\partial g}{\partial v}=u\cdot\dfrac{d}{dv}f(u^2,2uv)+0 \cdot f(u^2,2uv)=u\cdot\left(\dfrac{\partial f}{\partial x}(x,y)\dfrac{dx}{dv}+\dfrac{\partial f}{\partial y}(x,y)\dfrac{dy}{dv}\right)=2u^2\dfrac{\partial f}{\partial y}(x,y)$

And then:

$\dfrac{\partial}{\partial u}\left(\dfrac{\partial g}{\partial v}\right)=\dfrac{\partial}{\partial u}\left(2u^2\cdot\dfrac{\partial f}{\partial y}(x,y)\right)=4u\cdot\dfrac{\partial f}{\partial y}(x,y)+2u^2\cdot\dfrac{\partial}{\partial u}\left(\dfrac{\partial f}{\partial y}(x,y)\right)= 4u\cdot\dfrac{\partial f}{\partial y}(x,y)+2u^2\cdot\left(\dfrac{\partial^2f}{\partial x\partial y}(x,y)\dfrac{dx}{du}+\dfrac{\partial^2f}{\partial y^2}(x,y)\dfrac{dy}{du}\right)=4u\cdot\dfrac{\partial f}{\partial y}(x,y)+2u^2\cdot\left(2u\dfrac{\partial^2f}{\partial x\partial y}+2v\dfrac{\partial^2f}{\partial y^2}\right)$

Well, is this correct? I'm stuck again...

Answer (score 1):

Recall that by the Chain Rule for paths:

$$\frac{d}{dt}\Bigr|_t f(c(t)) = \nabla f(c(t)) \cdot c'(t)$$

Using the above fact and Product Rule we have:

$$\frac{\partial g}{\partial u} = \frac{d}{du} \left(u \cdot f \circ (u^2,2uv)\right) = u \cdot \frac{d}{du} f(u^2,2uv)+ f(u^2,2uv)$$

now finish!

Answer (score 0):

Your computations are true, so you just need to plug in the numbers.

As we have (u,v)=(1,1), we get (x,y)=(1,2), so now use those equations in the given information. Answer should be **-4**